# How to catch Stream Error in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, io, actionscript, http-get

I have the following piece of code, which attempts to `GET` a publicly hosted (AWS S3) file.

```
private function ShowS3Message():void
{
    // Attempt to download file from AWS
    var descriptor:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
    var ns:Namespace = descriptor.namespaceDeclarations()[0];
    var url:String = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/some-url/file-" + descriptor.ns::versionLabel.split(".").join("-") + ".txt";
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

    // Set up callback function
    try{
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, awsFetchCallback);                      
        loader.load(urlRequest);
    }catch(error:Error){}   
}
```

This is the callback function:

```
/**
 * Callback function for AWS message file
 */
private function awsFetchCallback(event:Event):void
{
    var data = event.target.data;

    // show dialog
    var msb:InformationMessageBox = new InformationMessageBox();
    msb.mText = data;
    msb.open(this, true);
}
```

When the file exists, there is no problem, and the code runs fine.
When the file doesn't exist, this throws a StreamError, despite the catch block.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture the IO error event, there is not exception thrown when the file does not exist.

`loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);`

and then create your own error handler function.

more details in the doc here :
https://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

If you just want to drown the error (because you seem to know the file may not exist sometimes) it is sufficient to create an empty error event handler.

Comment: What if I just want to drown the error? I know the file will not exist sometimes.